# Fetching data with respect to array with in array Json

Tags: android, json, listview, baseadapter

I need to fetch two `arrays` from a **`json`** response
Here is my response.

```
{
"data": [
    {
        "sub_cat": [
            {
                "id": "770",
                "cat_id": "14",
                "sub_category": "Pan America"
            },
            {
                "id": "771",
                "cat_id": "14",
                "sub_category": "John Players"
            }
        ],
        "id": "14",
        "cat_id": "x",
        "category": "Casual shirts"
    },
    {
        "sub_cat": [
            {
                "id": "770",
                "cat_id": "14",
                "sub_category": "Pan America"
            },
            {
                "id": "771",
                "cat_id": "14",
                "sub_category": "John Players"
            },
            {
                "id": "835",
                "cat_id": "15",
                "sub_category": "Roadster"
            },
            {
                "id": "836",
                "cat_id": "15",
                "sub_category": "wildcraft"
            }
        ],
        "id": "15",
        "cat_id": "x",
        "category": "Jackets"
    },
    {
        "sub_cat": [
            {
                "id": "770",
                "cat_id": "14",
                "sub_category": "Pan America"
            },
            {
                "id": "771",
                "cat_id": "14",
                "sub_category": "John Players"
            },
            {
                "id": "835",
                "cat_id": "15",
                "sub_category": "Roadster"
            },
            {
                "id": "836",
                "cat_id": "15",
                "sub_category": "wildcraft"
            },
            {
                "id": "833",
                "cat_id": "154",
                "sub_category": "Pepe jeans"
            },
            {
                "id": "834",
                "cat_id": "154",
                "sub_category": "John players"
            }
        ],
        "id": "154",
        "cat_id": "x",
        "category": "Jeans"
    }
],
"status": 100
}
```

While trying to fetch data, and put it in to a list adapter in which i want to display categories in one text box and subcategories in other with comma separation.
Like this:

```
Category : Jeans

Sub Category :John players,Pepe jeans,Pan America,Roadster,wildcraft
```

I tried implementing this by creating model class for both `category` and sub category. Getting category correctly, but getting all `subcategories`.

Comment: share your code and let us know what you have tried so far

Comment: hi praveen did you get the solution.

Comment: Noo @Mohammadnabil

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is code for same:

```
 try{
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

        ArrayList<String> categoryList = new ArrayList<>();

        HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> allCategory = new HashMap<>();
        JSONArray dataArray  = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
        for(int i=0;i<dataArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject internalObject = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

            categoryList.add(internalObject.getString("category"));

            JSONArray jsonArray = internalObject.getJSONArray("sub_cat");

            ArrayList<String> subCategoryList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int j=0;j<jsonArray.length();j++)
            {
                subCategoryList.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("sub_category"));
            }

            allCategory.put(categoryList.get(i),subCategoryList);
        }

        Log.d("Check",hashMap+" ");
    }
    catch (Exception exe)
    {
        exe.printStackTrace();
    }
```

You will get `categoryList` for all category and `allCategory` containing Hashmap. For mapping of category with its list of sub_categories.

### Edited

**Here is MainActivity.java class from where list is called:**

```
public class MainActivity extends Activity {

ExpandableListAdapter listAdapter;
ExpandableListView expListView;


HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> allCategory;
private ArrayList<String> categoryList;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);
    String[] mStrings = new String[20];

    allCategory= new HashMap<>();


    // get the listview
    expListView = (ExpandableListView) findViewById(R.id.lvExp);

    String jsonString = "{\n" +
            "\"data\": [\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "        \"sub_cat\": [\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"id\": \"770\",\n" +
            "                \"cat_id\": \"14\",\n" +
            "                \"sub_category\": \"Pan America\"\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"id\": \"771\",\n" +
            "                \"cat_id\": \"14\",\n" +
            "                \"sub_category\": \"John Players\"\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "        ],\n" +
            "        \"id\": \"14\",\n" +
            "        \"cat_id\": \"x\",\n" +
            "        \"category\": \"Casual shirts\"\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "        \"sub_cat\": [\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"id\": \"770\",\n" +
            "                \"cat_id\": \"14\",\n" +
            "                \"sub_category\": \"Pan America\"\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"id\": \"771\",\n" +
            "                \"cat_id\": \"14\",\n" +
            "                \"sub_category\": \"John Players\"\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"id\": \"835\",\n" +
            "                \"cat_id\": \"15\",\n" +
            "                \"sub_category\": \"Roadster\"\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"id\": \"836\",\n" +
            "                \"cat_id\": \"15\",\n" +
            "                \"sub_category\": \"wildcraft\"\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "        ],\n" +
            "        \"id\": \"15\",\n" +
            "        \"cat_id\": \"x\",\n" +
            "        \"category\": \"Jackets\"\n" +
            "    },\n" +
            "    {\n" +
            "        \"sub_cat\": [\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"id\": \"770\",\n" +
            "                \"cat_id\": \"14\",\n" +
            "                \"sub_category\": \"Pan America\"\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"id\": \"771\",\n" +
            "                \"cat_id\": \"14\",\n" +
            "                \"sub_category\": \"John Players\"\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"id\": \"835\",\n" +
            "                \"cat_id\": \"15\",\n" +
            "                \"sub_category\": \"Roadster\"\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"id\": \"836\",\n" +
            "                \"cat_id\": \"15\",\n" +
            "                \"sub_category\": \"wildcraft\"\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"id\": \"833\",\n" +
            "                \"cat_id\": \"154\",\n" +
            "                \"sub_category\": \"Pepe jeans\"\n" +
            "            },\n" +
            "            {\n" +
            "                \"id\": \"834\",\n" +
            "                \"cat_id\": \"154\",\n" +
            "                \"sub_category\": \"John players\"\n" +
            "            }\n" +
            "        ],\n" +
            "        \"id\": \"154\",\n" +
            "        \"cat_id\": \"x\",\n" +
            "        \"category\": \"Jeans\"\n" +
            "    }\n" +
            "],\n" +
            "\"status\": 100\n" +
            "}";

    // preparing list data
    prepareListData(jsonString);

    listAdapter = new ExpandableListAdapter(this, categoryList, allCategory);


    // setting list adapter
    expListView.setAdapter(listAdapter);


}


/*
 * Preparing the list data
 */
private void prepareListData(String jsonString) {
    try{
        JSONObject jsonObject = new JSONObject(jsonString);

       categoryList = new ArrayList<>();


        JSONArray dataArray  = jsonObject.getJSONArray("data");
        for(int i=0;i<dataArray.length();i++)
        {
            JSONObject internalObject = dataArray.getJSONObject(i);

            categoryList.add(internalObject.getString("category"));

            JSONArray jsonArray = internalObject.getJSONArray("sub_cat");

            ArrayList<String> subCategoryList = new ArrayList<>();
            for(int j=0;j<jsonArray.length();j++)
            {
                subCategoryList.add(jsonArray.getJSONObject(j).getString("sub_category"));
            }

            allCategory.put(categoryList.get(i),subCategoryList);
        }

        Log.d("Check",allCategory+" ");
    }
    catch (Exception exe)
    {
        exe.printStackTrace();
    }

}
}
```

**Here is Expandlist Adapter:**

```
public class ExpandableListAdapter extends BaseExpandableListAdapter {


HashMap<String,ArrayList<String>> listDataEditText;

int expandedGroup=0;

private Context _context;
private List<String> _listDataHeader; // header titles
// child data in format of header title, child title
private HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> _listDataChild;






public ExpandableListAdapter(Context context, List<String> listDataHeader,
                             HashMap<String, ArrayList<String>> listChildData) {
    this._context = context;
    this._listDataHeader = listDataHeader;
    this._listDataChild = listChildData;

    listDataEditText  = new HashMap<>();

    for(int j=0;j<listDataHeader.size();j++) {
        ArrayList<String> preInsertion = new ArrayList<>();
        for (int i =0;i<this._listDataChild.get(_listDataHeader.get(j)).size();i++)
        {
                preInsertion.add("");
        }

        listDataEditText.put(listDataHeader.get(j),preInsertion);

    }

}


@Override
public Object getChild(int groupPosition, int childPosititon) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .get(childPosititon);
}

@Override
public long getChildId(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return childPosition;
}




@Override
public View getChildView(final int groupPosition, final int childPosition,
                         boolean isLastChild, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {




    final String childText = (String) getChild(groupPosition, childPosition);

    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
    TextView txtListChild = convertView.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);






    txtListChild.setText(childText);
    return convertView;
}





@Override
public int getChildrenCount(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataChild.get(this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition))
            .size();
}

@Override
public Object getGroup(int groupPosition) {
    return this._listDataHeader.get(groupPosition);
}

@Override
public int getGroupCount() {
    return this._listDataHeader.size();
}

@Override
public long getGroupId(int groupPosition) {
    return groupPosition;
}

@Override
public View getGroupView(final int groupPosition, boolean isExpanded,
                         View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    String headerTitle = (String) getGroup(groupPosition);
    if (convertView == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this._context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        convertView = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_group, null);
    }

    TextView lblListHeader = (TextView) convertView
            .findViewById(R.id.lblListHeader);
    lblListHeader.setTypeface(null, Typeface.BOLD);
    lblListHeader.setText(headerTitle);




    return convertView;
}

@Override
public boolean hasStableIds() {
    return false;
}

@Override
public boolean isChildSelectable(int groupPosition, int childPosition) {
    return true;
}



 }
```

and here is list items:

for GroupView "list_group":

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:layout_editor_absoluteY="81dp">

<RelativeLayout
    android:id="@+id/relativeLayout"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListHeader"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_marginLeft="48dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="33dp" />


</RelativeLayout>
</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

for Child View "list_item":

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent">

<LinearLayout
    android:id="@+id/linearLayout4"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_marginBottom="8dp"
    android:layout_marginEnd="8dp"
    android:layout_marginStart="8dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="8dp"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    app:layout_constraintBottom_toBottomOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintEnd_toEndOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintHorizontal_bias="0.194"
    app:layout_constraintStart_toStartOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintTop_toTopOf="parent"
    app:layout_constraintVertical_bias="0.137">

    <TextView
        android:id="@+id/lblListItem"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_marginLeft="20dp"
        android:text="TextView"
        android:textColor="#000000"
        android:textSize="17dp" />

</LinearLayout>


</android.support.constraint.ConstraintLayout>
```

Try it and let me know if need more.

### Edited latest

Use this SimpleAdapter for showing all sub_categories list:

```
public class SimpleAdapter extends BaseAdapter {


ArrayList<String> stringArrayList;
Context context;

public SimpleAdapter(Context context,ArrayList<String> stringArrayList)
{
    this.context = context;
    this.stringArrayList = stringArrayList;
}

@Override
public int getCount() {
    return stringArrayList.size();
}

@Override
public Object getItem(int i) {
    return null;
}

@Override
public long getItemId(int i) {
    return 0;
}

@Override
public View getView(int i, View view, ViewGroup viewGroup) {
    if (view == null) {
        LayoutInflater infalInflater = (LayoutInflater) this.context
                .getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE);
        view = infalInflater.inflate(R.layout.list_item, null);
    }
    TextView txtListChild = view.findViewById(R.id.lblListItem);






    txtListChild.setText(stringArrayList.get(i));

    return view;
}
}
```

and make main layout as:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:orientation="vertical"
android:padding="5dp"
>



<ListView
    android:id="@+id/listView"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="fill_parent" >
</ListView>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: Upvote my answer if it works

Comment: how can i get these values in adapter ? i need to load these into a list view.

Comment: @Praveen you can pass this "hashmap" in constructor of adapter, so that you can be able to use it there.

Comment: @Praveen can you please upvote my answer.

Comment: Tried passing hashmap to adapter. But not getting data. How can i access each category and its corresponding sub category and print it into list view ? @ankit patidar

Comment: Wait i will give you adapter class and xml related to it.

Comment: See my edited Answer

Comment: I cannot use expandable listview here. I need the data in a simple listview using base adapter.

Comment: Bro i cannot help you more. I am tierd helping you. Lets ok. will do it also

Comment: See my "EDITED_LATEST", it will work as excepted.

Answer (score 0):

```
JsonObject root = new JsonObject(your json);
JsonArray data =  root.getJsonArray("data");
for loop data.size
inside loop 
JsonObject jObj = data.getJsonObject(i);
JsonArray sub_cat = jObj.getJsonArray("sub_cat");
 for loop int j=0 to sub_cat.length
inside loop 
JsonObject obj= sub_cat .getJsonObject(i);
String sub_category = obj.getString("sub_category");// here you will get all sub_category data
```